# How to get financial balance of the region laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, query-builder

I'm building a financial system using Laravel (school assignment) but I'm stuck. How do I get the remaining balance for each region using Laravel?

I have two tables. first table "keuangan" its mean "finance" in english. the second is region.
have many to many relationships

**In my "keuangan" table**
[keuangan table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pru5R.png)

to get income data, i use this.
By the way, i am sorry if this is difficult to understand -- i used Indonesian language in my column name

```
$dataPemasukan = Region::addSelect(['totalPendapatan' => Keuangan::selectRaw('sum(jumlah) as total')
                         ->whereColumn('region_id', 'regions.id')
                         ->Where('status', 'Lunas')
                         ->where('tipe_transaksi', 'pemasukan')
                         ->groupBy('region_id')])
                 ->orderBy('totalPendapatan', 'DESC')->get();
```

its return region income
[region income data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fiEQ.png)

for expense data i do the same thing, but I just changed *where('tipe_transaksi', 'pengeluaran')* its mean 'type_transaction', 'expense'.

to get the remaining balance. should just subtracting (income - expense) rigth?..

thats my problems.

in blade view i try like this

```
 @foreach ($dataPemasukan as $d)
 @foreach ($dataPengeluaran as $p)
  <tr>
  <td>{{ $d->region }}</td>
  <td style="color: #42a4ff">-Rp.@convert($d->totalPendapatan - $p->totalPengeluaran)</td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

it turns out like this
[blade view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8QGe.png)

so How do I get financial balance of the region in laravel using eloquent?
thank you...

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: I have mentioned in the question. the proble is ' how to get the remaining balance for each region using laravel'